# Parsing API data which contain object (Klaxon) (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have API response which contain object (graphic)

```
[
    {
        "code": 200,
        "status": "OK",
        "FirstDay": "2019-11-18",
        "LastDay": "2019-11-24",
        "graphic": {
            "2019-11-23": [
                {
                    "godzinaStart": "08:30",
                    "godzinaStop": "10:00",
                    "przedmiot": "Matematyka dyskretna",
                    "sala": "32AK8",
                    "nauczyciel": "xxx",
                    "grupy": "1K131; 1K132; 1K133; 1K134; 1K135; 2K131",
                    "typ": "wykład"
                },
            ],
            "2019-11-24": [
                {
                    "godzinaStart": "08:30",
                    "godzinaStop": "10:00",
                    "przedmiot": "Podstawy informatyki",
                    "sala": "308K",
                    "nauczyciel": "xxx",
                    "grupy": "1K131",
                    "typ": "laboratorium"
                },
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I have to parse this JSON to object in Kotlin. So i made class with parameters

```
class GraphicAPIResponse(
    var code: Int,
    var status: String,
    var errorMessage: String = "",
    var FirstDay: String = "",
    var LastDay: String = "",
    var graphic: JsonObject? = null OR var graphic: JsonArray<Any>? = null (I tried both)
)
```

I'm parsing data by this function

```
val responeAPI = Klaxon().parseArray<GraphicAPIResponse>(response)
```

When graphic is `JsonObiect` type appliaction throw error

```
I/System.out: ERROR -> Unable to instantiate JsonObject with parameters []
```

When graphic is `JsonArray<Any>` type, here's error

```
I/System.out: ERROR -> Unable to instantiate GraphicAPIResponse with parameters [LastDay: 2019-11-24, code: 200, status: OK, graphic: java.lang.Object@aef265a, FirstDay: 2019-11-18]
```

I'm trying to resolve the problem from 2 hours. Can someone help me please? :(

@EDIT

Thank You @Alexey Romanov

That help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a type for the nested object:

```
class Lesson(val godzinaStart: String, val godzinaStop: String, ...)
```

and use it in `GraphicAPIResponse`:

```
class GraphicAPIResponse(
    var code: Int,
    var status: String,
    var errorMessage: String = "",
    var FirstDay: String = "",
    var LastDay: String = "",
    var graphic: Map<String, Lesson> = mapOf()
)
```

(though honestly, I'd expect `JsonObject` to work as well)